# change event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I generate a dropdownList dynamicly with jquery Ajax , generated dropdown's id
is `specificationAttribute` . I want create add event for new tag was generated (`specificationAttribute`) , to do this I created Belowe `script` in `window.load`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#specificationattribute', function () {
    alert("Clicked Me !");
});
```

but it does not work . 
I try any way more like `click` , `live` but I cant any result.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a65m11b3/4/)

**Code from fiddle:**

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $("#specificationCategory").change(function () {
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected");
        if (selected.val().trim().length == 0) {
            ShowMessage('please selecet ...', 'information');
        }
        else {

            var categoryId = selected.val();
            var url = $('#url').data('loadspecificationattributes');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { categoryId: categoryId, controlId: 'specificationattribute' },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#specificationattributes').html(data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.error);

                }
            });

        }

    });



    $(document).on('change', '#specificationAttribute', function () {
        alert("changed ");

    });
    }
```

Comment: getting error in console?

Comment: @guradio no I dont get any errors

Comment: Can you post the markup as well ?

Comment: At the time you attach the event handler, are you sure the element with id specificationAttribute exists?

Comment: is there any other element with same id??

Comment: @Konst yes `specificationAttribute` exists and just i have one element by this id

Comment: Uthman, can you set up your example as a jsfiddle? It will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I run this code in firebug and console and return `1` : `$('#specificationattribute').length`

Comment: the question is at which time do you call that code. Would be good to see your markup / window.load completely.

Comment: Is the ID `specificationattribute` or `specificationAttribute`? You used one in the sample and another in your comment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a65m11b3/4/

Comment: @BrandonGano tag Id id `specificationattribute `

Comment: No `html` appears at linked jsfiddle?

Comment: I cant add html in jsfiddel becusae I generated new tag with `PartialView` in `ASP.NET MVC `

Comment: __ID must be unique__

Comment: @RayonDabre `Id` is `unique` , I'm sure

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#specificationAttribute', function () {` will work for only single element...

Comment: Try writing the code you mentioned in the success event of ajax. It should work then!

Comment: The fiddle has syntax error(s), is that just a typo? Post the partial view rendered HTML, that will be sufficient to debug this; we have nothing beyond the syntax issue here at present.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss where is syntax error ?

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bg6vu46q/

Comment: I added an answer with the syntax issues noted and some sample markup (the ID in question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fiddle has syntax errors.  Since a dropdownlist generates a select, let's use one.

For my answer I used THIS HTML, more on this later: things did not match in your code

```
<select id="specificationAttribute" name="specificationAttribute">
</select>
```

Code updated: (see inline comments, some are suggestions, some errors)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#specificationCategory").on('change',function() {
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected");
    // if there is a selection, this should have a length so use that
    // old:  if (selected.val().trim().length == 0) {
    if (!selected.length) { // new
    // NO clue what this is and not on the fiddle so commented it out
    //  ShowMessage('please selecet ...', 'information');
      alert("select something a category");// lots of ways to do this
    } else {
      var categoryId = selected.val();
      var url = $('#url').data('loadspecificationattributes');
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          categoryId: categoryId,
          controlId: 'specificationattribute'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
           // THIS line id does not match my choice of specificationAttribute so I changed it
          $('#specificationAttribute').html(data);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          alert(response.error);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  // THIS should work with the markup I put as an example
  $(document).on('change', '#specificationAttribute', function() {
    alert("changed ");
  });
});// THIS line was missing parts
```

Comment: Example fiddle with events that work outside the missing HTML that we have not knowledge of, so I simply appended an option  to the list and the change does fire on that. https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/a65m11b3/6/

Answer (score 4):

@Uthman, it might be the case that you have given different id to select and using wrong id in onchange event as i observed in the jsfiddle link  https://jsfiddle.net/a65m11b3/4/`

```
success: function (data) {
        $('#specificationattributes').html(data);
        },and  $(document).on('change', '#specificationAttribute', function () {
        alert("changed ");

    });  $(document).on('change', '#specificationAttribute', function () {
    alert("changed ");

});.
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesnt work because at the moment of attaching event your html element doesnt existi yet.

What you need are delegated events. Basically, you attach event to parent element + you have selector for child (usually by classname or tagname). That way event fires for existing but also for elements that meet selector added in future.

Check documentation here:
https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Especially part with this example:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr",      
function() {
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: He's using a delegated event handler.